# Popover arrow off center when setting UIPopoverPresentationController's barButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uipopovercontroller, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` with an image on my navigation controller:

```
    infoItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: infoImage,
                               style: .plain, 
                               target: self,
                               action: #selector(infoAction))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoItem
```

When tapping I do:

```
@objc func infoAction()
{
    let popoverContentController = InfoViewController()

    popoverContentController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    popoverContentController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    popoverContentController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self

    self.present(popoverContentController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This then calls out to `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` functions:

```
func prepareForPopoverPresentation(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController)
{
    popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .any
    popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = infoItem  <<=====
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController,
                               traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
{
    return .none
}
```

There `<<=====` I set the `barButtonItem`. I now expect the popover arrow to point at the center of this item. But it does not:

[image: Arrow is right from center]

Looking at the view hierarchy (below), my image is horizontally centred in the rectangular bar button. It's not at the left side at all, which would explain the popover arrow misalignment.

[image: View Hierarchy]

Any ideas what I'm missing here, or how this can be corrected?